# Solr unify categories Imports from two sources

Tags: solr, lucene, categories

We are looking to use solr in our new search feature. We are importing two mysql products databases into one solr instance. Everything is working fine but we have found that the categories from the two db's don't match.

e.g. Category 1 from DB1 is Electronics, category 1 from DB2 is Sport and Leisure.

Has anyone got any suggestions on how we proceed with this? Are we going to have to run a normalisation process before we import the products into solr or does solr have things like lookup tables?

Any suggestions or hints on where to look would be much appreciated.

Comment: i'm pretty sure, that you need to do normalization